# Sign Extension in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, verification

what is the difference between the following 3 sign extensions

```
wire signed [7:0] a;

wire signed [10:0] a_sxtnd1;
wire signed [10:0] a_sxtnd2;
wire signed [10:0] a_sxtnd3;

assign a_sxtnd1 = $signed(a);
assign a_sxtnd2 = $signed(  { {3{a[7]}} ,a}  );
assign a_sxtnd3 = $signed(  { 3'd0 ,a}  );
```

What are the differences and anyone of them will fail?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `$signed` in all three assignments.

In the first assignment to `a_sxtnd1`, both the LHS and RHS are signed, to `a` will be implicitly sign extended from 8 bits to 11 bits

In the second assignment to `a_sxtnd2`, you are explicitly sign extending `a` to an 11-bit result.

In the third assignment to `a_sxtnd3`, you are explicitly zero extending `a` to an 11-bit result.

So the third assignment is not like the other two, if that is what you mean by "fail"